# How to initialize object properly and start from clean slate?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've got this class:

```
Ext.define('Customer_Portal_UI.FormParameters', {
constructor: function (c) {
    Ext.each(this.ParticipantFormParameters, function (field) {
        if (field.toFieldSet != null) {
            var fieldSetName = c.targetFieldSetPrefix + field.toFieldSet;
            field.toFieldSet = fieldSetName;
        }
    });
},
ParticipantFormParameters: [
    { name: 'service_executive_account_Number', visible: false },
    { name: 'firstname', visible: true, displayText: 'Firstname', toFieldSet: 'GeneralInfoFS', allowBlank: false },
    { name: 'lastname', visible: true, displayText: 'Lastname', toFieldSet: 'GeneralInfoFS', allowBlank: false },
    { name: 'gendercode', visible: true, hasCheckbox: true, displayText: 'Gender', toFieldSet: 'GeneralInfoFS', xtype: 'combo', allowBlank: false },
]
});
```

If I do this once:

```
var formParams = Ext.create(Customer_Portal_UI.FormParameters, { targetFieldSetPrefix: 'add' });
console.log(formParams.ParticipantFormParameters[0].toFieldSet);
```

I will get `addGeneralInfoFS`.

But if I create this object many times, I'll get `addGeneralInfoFS, addaddGeneralInfoFS, addaddaddGeneralInfoFS`

What is going on here ? I tried `delete formParams` but when I initialize an object if the same type again, same problem.

Is it ExtJS or a javascript problem ? I find it weird I need to put effort into simply destroying objects...

**EDIT**: Ah! I found this in the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/core/manual/content/classsystem.html):

> When placing items in the prototype of the prototype, they will be
>   shared across all instances of the class. Unless you specifically want
>   to do this, you should only put "primitive" types inside the prototype
>   definition.

The question now is how to I declare members without them being "in the prototype" ? That's nice, but where does `ParticipantFormParameters` go exactly then ? I don't want it in the config cause it's dirty, I'll have to drag this huge (the real code has much more items in the array) block of javascript markup everytime I initialize the object ?

I've refactored things in my application with this approach and I'm completely paralized until this works...I cannot unrefactor...

Thank you.

Comment: You're putting the objects on the prototype, which means they are shared across all instances.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli So am I doing something wrong javascript wise or ExtJS class system wise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you modify the property ? Use two different variables. This could be the solution :

```
 (...)
  Ext.each(this.ParticipantFormParameters, function (field) {
        if (field.toFieldSet != null) {
            var fieldSetName = c.targetFieldSetPrefix + field.toFieldSetRaw;
            field.toFieldSet = fieldSetName;
        }
    });
},
ParticipantFormParameters: [
    { name: 'service_executive_account_Number', visible: false },
    { name: 'firstname', visible: true, displayText: 'Firstname', toFieldSetRaw: 'GeneralInfoFS', allowBlank: false },
```

Comment: I have found another solution in the meantime, but I'll mark this one as answer too since it is a perfectly legit approach IMO. Thanks.